# Data Management of Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, data-management

I have encountered some problems during writing VBA codes for summarizing data in a new workbook.

I don't know how to write a table here, so I am pasting a screenshot of it instead.

[image: Data source]

[image: Data Output]

I would like to write VBA code to auto-calculate the number of particular categories (such as A minus C) according to their date and country and generate a table like the second screenshot.

I have tried writing the exact reference for each column of output, but it is too clumsy to do and more new countries may add to the data source and the exact reference will be invalid.

I am not sure it is possible to search and sum particular countries and then auto-minus the data by categories by a double loop or creating arrays.

I am still a newbie on VBA.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ShName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Number As Integer

    Number = Worksheets("MgrSummary").Range("D2").Value
    Worksheets("MgrSummary").Range("C3").Value = Worksheets("MgrFull").Range("Y1").Value    'transfer the necessary data from MgrFull
    Worksheets("MgrSummary").Range("D3").Value = Worksheets("MgrFull").Range("Y2").Value
    Worksheets("MgrSummary").Range("D2").Value = (Year(Worksheets("MgrSummary").Range("D3").Value) - 2011) * 12 + Month(Worksheets("MgrSummary").Range("D3").Value) + 5
    Number = Worksheets("MgrSummary").Range("D2").Value

    Cells(Number - 36, 4).Value = Number              'Month number
    Cells(Number - 37, 4).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[1]C="""","""",IF(R[1]C-1<=5,"""",R[1]C-1))"
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Range(ActiveCell.Address, Cells(5, 4))

    Cells(Number - 36, 5) = Cells(3, 4).Value         'month and year
    Cells(Number - 37, 5).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",EOMONTH(R[1]C,-1))"
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Range(ActiveCell.Address, Cells(5, 5))

    Cells(Number - 36, 2) = Cells(3, 3).Value         'Ticker
    Cells(Number - 37, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C"
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Range(ActiveCell.Address, Cells(5, 2))

    ShName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MgrSummary").Range("C3").Value

    For i = 0 To Number - 41                          'for loop
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 8).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(21, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(24, 1 + Number - i)    'position attribution
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 9).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(19, Number + 1 - i)    'No. of postion(L-S)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 10).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(22, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 11).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(19, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(22, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 12).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(19, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 13).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(22, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 14).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(19, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(22, Number + 1 - i)


        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 15).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(56, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(119, Number + 1 - i)    'Gross Country Exposure
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 16).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(57, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(120, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 17).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(58, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(59, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(121, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(122, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 18).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(60, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(66, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(123, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(129, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 19).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(61, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(124, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 20).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(63, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(126, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 21).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(64, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(127, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 22).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(70, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(133, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 23).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(62, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(68, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(67, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(68, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(71, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(72, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(69, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(125, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(131, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(132, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(130, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(128, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(134, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(135, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(128, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 24).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(73, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(74, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(136, Number + 1 - i) - Worksheets(ShName).Cells(137, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 25).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(Number - 36 - i, 24), Cells(Number - 36 - i, 15)))

        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 26).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(56, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(119, Number + 1 - i)    'Net country exposure
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 27).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(57, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(120, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 28).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(58, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(59, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(121, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(122, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 29).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(60, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(66, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(123, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(129, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 30).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(61, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(124, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 31).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(63, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(126, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 32).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(64, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(127, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 33).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(70, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(133, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 34).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(62, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(67, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(65, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(68, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(69, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(72, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(71, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(125, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(131, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(132, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(130, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(134, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(135, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(128, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 35).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(73, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(74, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(136, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(137, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 36).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(Number - 36 - i, 26), Cells(Number - 36 - i, 36)))

        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 37).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(77, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(140, Number + 1 - i)    'country exposure(attribution)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 38).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(78, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(141, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 39).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(79, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(80, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(142, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(143, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 40).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(81, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(87, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(144, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(150, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 41).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(82, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(145, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 42).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(84, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(147, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 43).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(85, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(148, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 44).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(91, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(154, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 45).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(83, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(88, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(86, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(89, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(90, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(92, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(93, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(146, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(149, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(151, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(152, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(153, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(155, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(156, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 46).Formula = Worksheets(ShName).Cells(94, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(95, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(136, Number + 1 - i) + Worksheets(ShName).Cells(137, Number + 1 - i)
        Worksheets("MgrSummary").Cells(Number - 36 - i, 47).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(Number - 36 - i, 37), Cells(Number - 36 - i, 47)))

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to check out the [tour]--you even earn a badge for it! You say you are still a newbie with VBA - does this mean you have not attempted to write VBA for this yet yourself? Or have you made an attempt and it just didn't work? If the latter, please share what you've tried, it will go a long way toward helping us provide a solution.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it for several weeks. I just upload my work to my post. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW You can use tools like this https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to insert tables (between code tags Ctrl +K)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be much easier to use a formula to get your expected result :

Sheet1 is :

[image]

Sheet2 and formula is :

[image]

`=SUMIFS(OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$18,0,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$C$1:$O$1,0)),Sheet1!$A$2:$A$18,"A",Sheet1!$B$2:$B$18,MID(Sheet2!B$1,FIND(" ",Sheet2!B$1)+1,LEN(Sheet2!B$1)))-SUMIFS(OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$18,0,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$C$1:$O$1,0)),Sheet1!$A$2:$A$18,"C",Sheet1!$B$2:$B$18,MID(Sheet2!B$1,FIND(" ",Sheet2!B$1)+1,LEN(Sheet2!B$1)))`

Edit for various data source:

Sheet1 is:

[image]

Sheet2 is :

[image]

Sheet3 is :

[image]

Formula is :

`=SUMIFS(OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet"&$G$1&"!$B$2:$B$18"),0,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,INDIRECT("Sheet"&$G$1&"!$C$1:$O$1"),0)),INDIRECT("Sheet"&$G$1&"!$A$2:$A$18"),"A",INDIRECT("Sheet"&$G$1&"!$B$2:$B$18"),MID(Sheet2!B$1,FIND(" ",Sheet2!B$1)+1,LEN(Sheet2!B$1)))-SUMIFS(OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet"&$G$1&"!$B$2:$B$18"),0,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,INDIRECT("Sheet"&$G$1&"!$C$1:$O$1"),0)),INDIRECT("Sheet"&$G$1&"!$A$2:$A$18"),"C",INDIRECT("Sheet"&$G$1&"!$B$2:$B$18"),MID(Sheet2!B$1,FIND(" ",Sheet2!B$1)+1,LEN(Sheet2!B$1)))`

Sheet number would be selected is sheet2 cell G1. You can slightly modify the formula if you are using different sheet names (e.g. INDIRECT("Sheet"&$G$1&"!$A$2:$A$18") would become INDIRECT($G$1&"!$A$2:$A$18")).

Issue with that formula is that it is not easily scalable and you loose the relative reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! It is an awesome method to do this.
Since the data source is much much much larger to the example graph shown above, and there are more versions of sheet 1, sheet 2 is to show a summarized result of a selected sheet. For example, if I write sheet 3(which is also a data source like sheet 1) in a particular cell in sheet 2, sheet two will then generate a summary of sheet 3. Would it be more convenient or efficient to use VBA code to generate the result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this easily with PowerQuery (In built in Get&Transform in data tab 2016, free add-in for 2013 from Microsoft > Powerquery tab).

**Note:**

1. I added headers for column A of `Category` and Column B of `Country`
2. I'm assuming you mean A - C as a subtraction, but easy to change otherwise by using Grouping and Sum operation. Let me know.

---

1) Select a cell in your data range and goto powerquery tab or data tab (2016) and select data > from table

[image: Data]

---

2) Select `Category` column > select header right hand side drop down arrow> remove empty

[image: Remove null rows]

---

3) Select all month columns (select first, hold down shift button, select last) then right click > unpivot columns

[image: Unpivot month columns]

[image: Unpivoted columns]

---

4) Select `Category` column and go to Transform > Pivot Column

Selecting Value as Values column

[image: Pivot values column]

[image: Pivoted category column]

---

5) Optional select Attribute click on the left hand side icon and change datatype for column to Date. You can then sort this column ascending.

```
[![Date][7]][7]
```

---

6) Goto Add Column > And give a name example AminusC and a formula e.g.

```
=[A]-[C]
```

Repeat for any other calculations you want.

[image: Custom column]

---

7) Select columns `A,B,C` and right click remove columns

---

8) Optional select `Country` column and Transform > Pivot column > Values column = AminusC

[image: Pivot Country column]

---

9) Home > Close and Load To Worksheet

[image: Close and load]

---

10) Observe result (note you can change column names in between to match your desired column headers and to distinguish between calculations. This was to show you the method.

[image: Result]